# How much is too much time for a rake test to be ran?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I have a project that the tests are far from ideal, It takes around 15 min to run all tests, and for me it is a problem. What is the maximum that a rake test should take?

I understand that this a personal take, please write a little bit of why as well, or paste a link to justify your answer, please.

Comment: Are you asking us to write reasons why your tests are taking so long? Will you CC us on the email to your boss also?

Comment: Would this be more suited to programmers SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a baseline, my current application has 2 sets of unit tests (for non-rails-dependent code and for rails-dependent code). 2 of the most time-consuming things in running rake in a rails environment is loading up rails and bundle exec. This is why we are moving as much of our testing into a non-rails-dependent, non-bundle-exec environment. So, as we touch parts of our existing system, we are moving the specs into the non-rails-dependent section.

Here is the breakdown of timing our current test suite:

time rake spec:no_rails
Finished in 0.14229 seconds
141 examples, 0 failures

real    0m0.981s
user    0m0.783s
sys 0m0.168s

time rake spec
Finished in 11.86 seconds
677 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending

real    0m28.613s
user    0m23.435s
sys 0m3.180s

I'm sure you can see why we are moving non-rails-dependent code examples away from the rails-dependent ones. There are a few other benefits to keeping your code from being dependent on rails, but the speed of tests is one of the most important. Minimizing the feedback cycle is imperative to get the most benefit out of your tests as regression.

**UPDATE**
Just as an update, as we move things over, here are the current stats for our specs. We definitely are finding both the speed to be an advantage, as well as the design pressure to isolate ourselves from rails. When you have your specs running this quickly, you can run them more frequently, which minimizes the feedback loop between doing something and seeing if the system still works.
time rake spec:no_rails
Finished in 0.36083 seconds
316 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
real    0m1.019s
user    0m0.858s
sys 0m0.147s

time rake spec:with_rails
Finished in 12.86 seconds
706 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending
real    0m21.316s
user    0m18.610s
sys 0m1.954s

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to answer without knowing the particulars. Do you have many test cases? I've heard of large systems with hundreds or even thousands of tests that need hours to complete a full suite.

OTOH you might have only a few tests that are slow. Have you tried segmenting the test cases to see if any take a particularly long time? Do you have tests that depend on potentially slow resources, like network or file system operations?

Comment: On the other hand Ruby1.9.2 has 940+ tests and runs in about a minute.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: That's only twice as many tests as my work project has.